# Show an activity on Long Click and close/hide on release (ACTION_UP)

Tags: android

**What I want**

A Text View when long clicked should open a new activity showing its details, when let go, i.e. when the onTouch ACTION_UP event fired, it should close the newly opened activity.

**How I am trying to achieve this**

Main Activity code:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent( (this, ShowDetailActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

ShowDetailActivity code:

```
    //OnCreate method
    view.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
                    // Log.i("INFO", "ontouch event");
                    if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                        Log.d("TouchTest", "Touch down");
                    } else if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                        Log.d("TouchTest", "Touch up");
                        onBackPressed();
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            }); 

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
    Log.i("INFO", "GOing back");
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

**Problem**

It works fine, except for the fact that when the newly opened details activity have to be re-tapped to be closed. I want that I long-click the textview and when the activity opens it closes on the same click release, it does so on the release of a new tap that I make.

EDIT:
I have changed question title from : Passing an event listener from one activity to another

Comment: why dont u use handler and close the activity after some time ?

Comment: If I Understood your question right, you need to display some info when its log pressed on the textview. You can try this with any overlay view that you can create at runtime.

Comment: @amalBit Any example code on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research I found out that activity events are registered only after an activity is created, so for an activity to handle the ACTION_UP event that event has to be  registered.

Therefore in my case the activity wasn't an option, I had to use fragments instead, here is what you need to do to be able to use fragments

1. Layout in which you need to have fragments should be a **RelativeLayout**
2. The activity on which you need to show fragments should be a child of **FragmentActivity**

Here is the MainActivity

```
  public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
        FrameLayout fl; 
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            fl = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frameTitle);
            TextView txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_view);
            txtView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {
                    sendMessage();
                    return true;
                }
            });
            txtView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    }
                    else if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                        fl.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
        public void sendMessage(){
            fl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
```

Here is the layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
    <TextView
         android:id="@+id/txt_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_view"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txt_view"
        android:text="@string/button_send" />
    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frameTitle"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone">
    <fragment 
          android:id="@+id/msg_fragment"
            android:name="com.example.holdview.MsgFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```